# ToolBarItem in xamarin.forms android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ToolBarItem in my xaml, this works perfectly on my android but not on iOS. Is there a way to achieve this on both platforms? Also, my app on iOS breaks when i include "Icon=""ic_action_more_vert.png""

**My xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


<ToolbarItem Text="About" 
                 Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                 Priority="0"
                 Order="Secondary"
                 Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Settings"
                 Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                 Priority="0"
                 Order="Secondary"
                 Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_1"/>



</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: is your page contained within a NavigationPage?  Otherwise there will not be a toolbar to display the Items on.  Also, what does "breaks" mean?  Do you get an error or exception?  What specifically is happening?  Are you sure your image exists in the iOS project in the proper folder with the correct build action?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the priority (1 or 0) and order (Primary or Secondary) of your two ToolbarItems.